# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 when Trying to delete an entry..

Tags: error, mysql

So, trying to delete an entry .. after the "ARE YOU SURE?"-page and the click on delete, I get the following error.

Anyone else had this problem?
I'm afraid of mySQL, so this is freaking me out :(

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

DELETE FROM `exp_channel_entries_autosave` WHERE `original_entry_id` IN ()

Filename: libraries/api/Api_channel_entries.php

Line Number: 490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by doing things in ee...

So here it is:
If you don't have a channel field group with a channel field in it associated with the channel.. it gives you this error.

So now you know :)